# View dataLayer's data in Google Analytics by event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I do not understand how to catch data from an event in google analytics.
I watch my event [image]

My dataLayer is like the documentation (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#cart)

[image]

My question is : How can i see that (product's data and actionField) in Google Analytics ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "step" is visible in the Checkout Behavior report in the E-Commerce-Section of the Conversions-Menu (it's displayed as a funnel step in the visualization and you can give it a proper name in the view settings).

Checkout options can be displayed as secondary dimensions, used in segments, custom reports and via the API (they are not part of the standard reports).